# How to manipulate numbers in array with for loop in JS

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, increment, decrement

I have a array:

> let numbers = [5, 10, 15, 25, 30];

I want to increment them all by one using a for loop. The result should be 6, 11, 16, 26 and 31.

But I can do this:

```
let numbers = [5, 10, 15, 25, 30];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  console.log(numbers + 1);
```

Comment: Use `numbers[i] + 1`

Comment: `arr.map(n => ++n)`.

Comment: Why user for loop? It's easily achievable by map

Comment: If mutation is desired, `Array.prototype.map` doesn't do the job. While an immutable style is nice, i don't think that is a topic relevant for such a basic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    numbers[i] += 1
}
console.log(numbers)
```

Output: `[6, 11, 16, 26, 31]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let numbers = [5, 10, 15, 25, 30]; 

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i]++
}
```

Comment: The assignment `numbers[i] =` is redundant, but probably what would be good to teach OP.

Comment: Ah you're right, updated!

Answer (score 0):

```
const numbers = [5, 10, 15, 25, 30];

const result = numbers.map(num => num + 1);
console.log(result); //[6, 11, 16, 26, 31]
```